# Where can I find an English translation of 'Il Fioretto della Bibbia'?

Tags: cultural-history

I am currently reading *The Cheese and the Worms*, in which the author (Carlo Ginzburg) frequently cites a works of the apocryphal gospels titled *Il Fioretto della Bibbia*, an Italian translation of a medieval Catalan chronicle compiled from various sources.

Are any surviving (English) translations of this works in circulation? I have tried searching for this title but most results are in Italian so it might have escaped me.

The original works was presumably written in Catalan, but since I do not know how this title is translated into English (*The Sword of the Bible* perhaps?), let alone Medieval Catalan, I haven't had much success in my search for the original either.

I'm currently using the Stack Exchange mobile app and can't find a link to the Do's and Don'ts so I apologize if this is off-topic.

Comment: I would argue that you are on topic - there is extensive discussion whether source requests are on topic in Meta.history.stackexchange, but (a) you're asking for a singular resource and (b) you were polite about it. Alas, I have no clue where to find the source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a source request, not a history question.

Comment: @TylerDurden Thanks for the feedback. Can you be more specific? I just had a look at the help center and couldn't find anything to support your close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell there are no English translations of this work, but here are links to 3 copies (housed in Italian collections):

- http://www.theeuropeanlibrary.org/tel4/search?query=Fioretto%20della%20Bibbia

And one in Barcelona:

- https://mcem.iec.cat/veure.asp?id_manuscrits=168

---

According to [this site](http://www.italinemo.it/riviste/sommario_rivistajs.php?fascicolo=RIVISTA+DI+LETTERATURA+ITALIANA%7C2006%7C1) and [this book](https://books.google.es/books?id=nh4DG4AsTuUC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=fiore+novello+fioretto+della+bibbia), *"Fioretto della Bibbia"* was also published under the name *"Fiore novello"*:

> Another book connected with the success of biblical translations was *Fiore novello* or *Fioretto della Bibbia*, a chronicle of antiquity which blended scriptural information with elements of profane history and even pagan mythology. A work as interesting as it has been little studied, and one which certainly existed in a variety of versions, the book enjoyed great success, both in manuscript and print.

Under this name I found this (*Fiore novello estratto dalla Bibbia*):

- https://www.gla.ac.uk/myglasgow/incunabula/a-zofauthorsa-j/bg.2.6/

This directory contains a number of listings of copies of this work, their publication date, and the institutions that held them (as of 1983):

- [Printed Italian Vernacular Religious Books 1465-1550 : a Finding List](https://books.google.es/books?id=yq08oeXxmhgC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22Fiore+novello%22), Anne Jacobson Schutte

And this one:

- [Documenting the Early Modern Book World: Inventories and Catalogues in Manuscript and Print](https://books.google.es/books?id=Ze_IAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA388&lpg=PA388&dq=%22fiore+novello%22), edited by Malcolm Walsby, Natasha Constantinidou

---

Additionally, there is this work from the collection:

> *I fatti di Giuseppe brano cavato dal Fioretto della Bibbia [a cura di Pietro Ferrato]*, Stabil. Tip. dei Fratelli Salmin alla Minerva

Whose full text is available here:

- https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_p1u_LIUBVDMC
- https://books.google.es/books?id=p1u_LIUBVDMC

---

The description of [this work](https://www.maremagnum.com/libri-antichi/storia-della-reina-ester-scritta-nel-buon-secolo-della/151070663) seems to claim that *"codex Magliabechiano IV, 107"* contains the *"Fioretto della Bibbia"*:

> **STORIA DELLA REINA ESTER SCRITTA NEL BUON SECOLO DELLA LINGUA E NON MAI FIN QUI STAMPATA.**
>
> Prima pubblicazione a stampa di una novella di ambientazione orientale rinvenuta dal curatore Francesco Zambrini nel **codice Magliabechiano IV, 107 contenente il Fioretto della Bibbia**. Esemplare n. 1 di una tiratura non specificata, su carta distinta.